# taking inputs from timePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am working in a project where the user inputs time in the TimePickerDialog. I want to take that input and store it in another variable and show it as a textView.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
TextView tv;
int hour,min;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    hour = hourOfDay;
                    min = minute;
                }
            }, hour, min, false);
            tpd.show();
            tv.setText(hour + ":" + min);
        }

        });
    }


}
```

When i run this app at first the textview shows 0:0 . i press the button the dialog comes up i set the time and press done but the textview does not change and only after i press the button again the textview changes to the previous input .  What i want is that when i press done in the timepickerdialog the textview would show the time that i have set. It is showing that value but only after i press the button again .

Comment: `tv.setText(hour + ":" + min);` move this line inside `onTimeSet` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
TextView tv;
int hour,min;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    hour = hourOfDay;
                    min = minute;
                    tv.setText(hour + ":" + min);
                }
            }, hour, min, false);
            tpd.show();
         }
     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the `TextView` when the done button is clicked. Right now your `TextView` doesn't get updated after the time picking is complete. Just change your code like below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    hour = hourOfDay;
                    min = minute;

                    //Place it here
                    tv.setText(hour + ":" + min);
                }
            }, hour, min, false);
            tpd.show();
        }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it's perfect